# How can Google autocomplete suggestions be captured through a browser plugin?

Tags: javascript, browser-plugin, keylogger

I use the Google Custom Search API to fetch the results that a user sees when Googling.  While I can get the results (approximately), one behavior the API does not (and cannot) capture is the autocomplete behavior of a user.  I want to know the autocomplete suggestions that are available to a user at various points (the last set, if only that's feasible) and the autocomplete result that a user clicks (if any).

I can't seem to find a quick JavaScript/jQuery solution for this, or a browser plugin that captures this autocomplete behavior.  Is there a way to do this, short of keystroke logging and then deriving the behavior from the logs?

Comment: sounds like a privacy thing to me, I'd hate to have a browser that allows capture of such data, are you sure that this is not prohibited by the browser Privacy Policy itself?

Comment: Not sure.  I wouldn't be surprised if Google captures this behavior somehow, though.  And that needs to be partly client-side (clicking of results) and not server-side.

Comment: not necessarily since Google's servers get your IP(or whatever it is they use to identify you) and the *final*  requested search query string in order to deliver the search results. If we are talking about Chrome only, it could be client-side but it would probably be holed up inside a native browser function, not exposed for use thru JS. Google can also guarantee compliance with their Privacy Policy. For a third-party like yourself, not so much. Anyways I'll lay low with the speculation thingy but I'm interested to see if an answer comes up.